# Read keyboard input when I read log cat with bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, logcat

I have created a .bat-file for Windows with

```
adb logcat -c
adb logcat
```

Start the .bat

Here I would add in the .bat that if the user presses the space key on the keyboard (or any other key) I want to continue with my bat.

```
adb logcat -v time -d > logcat.txt
```

This is what I try to achieve

Connect the phone to the computer.

Running my .bat-file

Work with my phone until I get to a crash (I can see the log cat works)

Click on space and everything from log cat saves to a file

Comment: Have you tryied `pause`?

Comment: Yes I have tryied pause.
Don't know if its because of logcat is running

Comment: You have shown three `adb` command lines - where do you need it to pause?

Comment: When the user click a key (ex space or enter key) I want to stop logcat and save it to a file.